# UIImagePickerController Navigation Bar Tint Color not working with iOS 13

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uiimagepickercontroller, ios13

I am presenting a modal controller which is a UIImagePickerController.

I am trying to change the `UIImagePickerController` navigation bars' tint colour.

Prior to iOS13 this worked fine;

```
imagePickerController.navigationBar.tintColor = .red
```

I have also tried;

```
imagePickerController.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .red
```

but still no joy.

What can I try next?

Comment: I've had the same issue. I haven't had a chance to try it yet but one solution I'm planning is to use `UINavigationBar appearance` just before creating the image picker and then resetting the appearance when dismissing the image picker.

Comment: It works! Hazaar!

Comment: You should post an answer below with your full implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was resolved with rmaddy's solution in the comments.

in `AppDelegate` implement;

```
func configureGlobalUI() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .red
}
```

then call in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

This works as I require the `tintColor` on all `navigationBar` appearances.

Comment: This is for the entire app, what if we need to change only for a specific ViewController. i.e UIImagePickerController. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -4):

You can just make UIView the size of the Navigation Bar and put it under navigation bar and make navigation bars color alpha=0.
I hope this helped. :)